# React Router v6 - createBrowserRouter Can not get error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I tried to use `createBrowserRouter` to create a new route (apart from the root `"/"`), but it seems not working. Can anyone help pointing out what could be missing?

[image]

Here is how index.js looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './app';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/", // This is working
    element: <App />,
  },
  {
    path: "/hello", // This get "Cannot GET /hello" error 
    element: <div>Hello</div>
  }
])

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  )
```

webpack common config:

```js
const path = require('path');

const babelLoaderRule = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      ]
    }
  }
}

const urlLoaderRule =  {
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
  loader: 'url-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[name].[ext]',
    outputPath: 'images',
    limit: 8192,
  }
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name]-bundle-[chunkhash:6].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [babelLoaderRule, urlLoaderRule]
  }
};
```

webpack dev config:

```js
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.config.js');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    port: 3000,
    compress: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      hash: false,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{        
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
        ]
    }]
  }
});
```

serve the app by:

```
"start": "webpack serve --open --config ./config/webpack.dev.config.js",
```

Comment: How are you starting your development server? Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: How are you hosting or serving the app? This is a server issue. The general gist is that the hosting service/server needs to serve the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to gather a sense of the sort of things that can/should be configured.

Comment: @dbuchet I am not using create-react-app, I updated my quetsion with how I server the app

Comment: Your server need to rewrite all urls to point to your index.html

Comment: Please [edit] to share all code as properly formatted and readable text/code snippets instead of posting images of text/code. Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable in the case of reproducible examples. See if adding `historyApiFallback: true` to `devServer` of your webpack config helps resolve the issue.

Comment: @DrewReese "historyApiFallback: true" gives http 304 which returns the <App /> instead of the new component

Comment: Cool, it is at least now serving the index.html file correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are missing actually rendering the router (*and routes*). Right now the app is only rendering the `App` component.

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <App />
</React.StrictMode>
```

Should be

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './app';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
  },
  {
    path: "/hello",
    element: <div>Hello</div>
  }
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

The dev webpack configuration should also specify `historyApiFallback: true` in the `devServer` property.

```js
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.config.js');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true, // <--
    static: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    port: 3000,
    compress: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      hash: false,
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{        
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
        ]
    }]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to see whether it is resolved.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './app';
import { createBrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <App />,
    },
    {
      path: '/hello',
      element: <div>Hello</div>,
    },
  ],
});

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Switch>{router}</Switch>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: `Switch` is a `react-router@5` export.